# routerLink directive with multiple dynamic parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I need to build this route **'id/name'** where id and name are **dynamic** parameters. I've tried next code:

```
<a [routerLink]="[list.id, list.name]">
```

But this shows an error

```
Blank expressions are not allowed in interpolated strings at column 0 in [{{ }}]
```

How I can fix that?

Comment: Doesn't sound like this error is coming from this code. Have you tried to hardcode the values like `<a [routerLink]="['id', 'name']">`?

Comment: can you try `<a [routerLink]="['/',list.id,list.name]">`, if you are using relative route link. (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#link-parameters-array)